# Make Javascript print string on every click

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

I'm trying to make JavaScript print a string every time I click on a button, but it will only print it the first time I click it.

JavaScript:

```
function MoreCameras() {
         document.getElementById("AddCamera").innerHTML = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='SSIDSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera SSID'></td><td><input type='text' name='NameSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Name'></td><td><input type='password' name='PasswordSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Password'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='EnabledSetup[]'/></td></tr>";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
     <div id="AddCamera"></div>
</table>
<button onclick="MoreCameras()">Add camera</button>
```

I have tried something like this, but I still can't make it work:

```
 function MoreCameras() {
        var div = document.getElementById("AddCamera").innerHTML,
            clone = "Long string here";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem you're having is that you're setting `innerHTML` rather than adding to it.

You can add to `innerHTML` by using the `+=` operator.

For example:

```js
function MoreCameras() {
  document.getElementById("AddCamera") += "... some string ...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this approach in your `MoreCameras` function:

1. Create a new `<tr></tr>` element.
2. Put inside your table row all your content (stored in a `newCamera` variable, for convenience).
3. Add the row to the table.

I also removed the useless `div` from inside the `table`.

```js
var newCamera = "<td><input type='text' name='SSIDSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera SSID'></td><td><input type='text' name='NameSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Name'></td><td><input type='password' name='PasswordSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Password'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='EnabledSetup[]'/></td>";

function MoreCameras() {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML = newCamera;
  document.getElementById("AddCamera").appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="MoreCameras()">Add camera</button>
<table id="AddCamera"></table>
```